# Detect touch on color spots at image(bitmap)

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to detect touches on red spots on image bellow, so after touch on spot I can make action.
I guess I need to detect touch coordinates, and check if it matches red spot. But how can I detect red spot position? Is it possible?
Note: I can choose image format if it helps, but probably we need work with bitmap.

I need to get dot position programmatically. I receive picture, I need to handle touch event's on dots. But I can receive different image with different dots positions

Thanks for all thoughts!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution I see is:

1- Get the imageView size as it might change depending on device screen size and/or resolution.

```
int IVwidth = imageView.getWidth();
int IVHeight = imageView.getHeight();
```

2- Get the Bitmap width/height and then find the mathmatical relation (ratio) between bitmap width and imageView width,
Simply:

```
float HeightRatio = (float)bm.getHeight() / (float)iv.getHeight();
float WidthRatio = (float)bm.getWidth() / (float)iv.getWidth();
```

lets say we have a bitmap of (800*600) size and an imageView of (400*300) size
this would give you a ratio of (2.0) for height and width.

3- Now when the event ImageViewTouched is raised, you can get the touch coordinates quite easy as the event will deliver them to you. Notice that catching the touch event is quite easy and simply can be implemented by adding this to the view;

```
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

            if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                int x = arg1.getX();
                int y = arg1.getY();
                int XonImage = x * WidthRatio;
                int YonImage = Y * HeightRatio;
                if(bm.getPixel(XonImage, YonImage) == Color.RED)
                {
                 // BINGOOOOOOO, do your magic here
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

For anymore info please ask without hesitation.
Cheers

Comment: Nice... What is `bm`?

Comment: bm is the Bitmap of the ImageView

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html). The view hierarchy should be:

```
<FrameLayout>
   <ImageView vineyard>
   <LinearLayout dots_holder>
      <ImageView dot1/>
      <ImageView dot2/>
      <ImageView dotn/>
   </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Your dots will be overlayed on the vineyard image and you can add an OnClickListener to each one. For positioning and dimensions of each dot ImageView, I would do some dynamic calculation in your code.

Comment: Problem here is that image comes with red dots. I need to detect touch on this dot so then I can show some info in popup.

Comment: Simply put an empty view over each dot. Same principle above applies.

Comment: But how to detect dot position? I have image with dots, but I don't know theirs position. I need to find it out from picture

Comment: Determine the percentage x/y of each dot. For example, the image is 344x253px. The first dot is at 110,135. 110/344 = 31.9% x and 135/253 = 53.3%. So that dot is 31.9% from left and 53.3% from the top.

Comment: I need to get dot position programmatically. I receive picture, I need to handle touch event's on dots. But I can receive different image with different dots positions

Comment: You should have made that clear in the question. I suggest looking at photo recognition algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

There's so many ways. You might be able to use SemperFly's method. There's also onTouchListeners for views, which would give you the coordinates. You may have to do translate the coordinates to handle different screen densities.

You also may be able to divide the image into a grid, which may simplify or avoid the math. Another option would be to chop the image into tiles. You can also use something like a RelativeLayout.

How accurate do you need the touch detection?

Comment: Problem here is that image comes with red dots. I need to detect touch on this dot so then I can show some info in popup.